# How to prevent apple watch app resign to background swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchkit

Im working on an training-like app where a started session should keep the app in focus. After about 5 minutes of not raising my wrist, it resigns to background and watch shows the standard complication. The app is still running, but I have to find it in the "dock"

Any ideas on how to prevent the app to loose focus during session? I don't need the screen to be on, but I need the app to show the stats/buttons whenever I raise my wrist.
I have found the 
`applicationWillResignActive()`
but this does not seem to have any functionality to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to use extended runtime sessions, which I think was introduced in watchOS 6.

The extended runtime sessions requires you to specifically list your session type, which I think in your case would qualify, as ‘Physical Therapy’. You are to choose in your project settings’ background modes section

That said, as I do not know what activity the app would be used for, it may also not qualify, if the activity is considered strenuous. In that case, look out for `HKWorkoutSession` instead, which kinda treats the workout like the default workouts app one, I believe, but I’m not sure if that’s what you want.

If you want to use the extended runtime sessions, you can:

1. Initialize session as `WKExtendedRuntimeSession()`
2. Assign delegate of the session (`WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate`)
3. Use delegate functions like `extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession)` to deal with when session is active.

Don’t forget to `session.start` to start the session, when needed.

Here’s some info that could further help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to vincent I found out the correct apple docs for this.

Got this to work with a SwiftUI view by wrapping it in a WKHostingController. As seen I just injected that HKWorkoutSession  into the SwiftUI view. I then start and stop from inside that view onAppear and onDissapear. 
Just posting if anyone else is struggling to find a solution. Beware, below is just a concept.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore

```
class ExerciseInterfaceController: WKHostingController<Plank>  {
var ed = (WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate)
let ws: HKWorkoutSession
override init() {

    let hs = HKHealthStore()
           let cnf = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
            cnf.activityType = .mindAndBody. //just for debugging
            cnf.locationType = .indoor 

           do {
               ws = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: hs, configuration: cnf)
           } catch {
              fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
           }

}
override var body: Plank {
    return Plank(workoutsession: ws)
}
```